# $A\times B=0$ with $A\ne0,\ B\ne0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem

$A\times B=0$, with $A$ is different from $0$. Both are complex matrices.

For this to be valid, $B$ should be the zero matrix. Is there any possibility $B$ can be different from zero, given that its dimensions are not the same than $A$'s? How can I choose $B$, in general, so as to comply with the condition?

$A$ is $N\times N$ and all its entries are different from zero, in general, while $B$ is $N\times2$.

Comment: Let $A$ have $1$ at the 3rd entry and $0$ elsewhere, as $B$ have $1$ at the 1st entry and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: A's entries are different from zero, in general. I have updated the question!

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Well, my example still works. My $A$ is not $0$. Unless what you mean is that you want $A$ to have all of its entries $\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ has the rows $a_j$ and $B$ has columns $b_k$ then the product $AB$ will have elements $\langle a_j, b_k\rangle$. So that $AB=0$ is equivalent to $\langle a_j, b_k\rangle=0$ (for all $j$ and $k$), that is $a_j$ and $b_k$ are perpendicular. We see this is always and the case when $a_j$ and $b_k$ are picked from subspaces that are orthogonal complements and only then.

So for example given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ this means that we need to consider the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by the rows of $A$. This orthogonal complement is of dimension $n-\operatorname{rank} A$ and if $\operatorname{rank} A\ne n$ we will find non-zero vectors there.

If you on the other hand want to create both $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=0$ you can first (at will) decompose $\mathbb R^n$ in two non-trivial orthogonal complemental subspaces (can be done by taking the spaces spanned by two disjoint subsets of an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb R^n$) and select rows for $A$ in one of them and columns of $B$ from the other.

Comment: I understand that, if A is given, then I have to choose every entry of B so that when performing the multiplication, all results will be zero. The thing is, are there infinite options? How could I choose the entries of B in a general way?

Comment: @Hans If $A$ is given it must have rank lower than $n$ otherwise you can't find such a $B$. Otherwise it's an infinite number of possibilities, but the possibilities may not be as interresting if $A$ has rank $n-1$ (after all it should already be clear that if $B$ fulfils the requirement then so does $cA$ for any constant $c$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_1,B_1$ be any two square matrices of size $k\times k$. Let $Z$ be the zero matrix of the same size.  Now construct two $2k\times 2k$ matrices $A,B$ in block forms $A=\pmatrix{A_1 & Z \\ Z &Z}, \ B=\pmatrix{Z&Z\\Z&B_1 }$
then it can be easily checked that $AB=0$. This works for matrices of even size. For odd, one can  append rows and columns of zeros appropriately to the above example.